# Diferença entre WADL e WSDL

Tags: web-service, wsdl

De forma simples, qual a diferença entre as especificações WSDL e WADL, no que se referem:

- Método de Acesso
- Limitações

Ainda não entendi quando devo utilizar um ou outro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eles são usados para diferentes implementações de serviços:

- [WSDL (*Web Services Description Language*)](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) é usado para descrever serviços que implementam o padrão SOAP, incluindo vários protocolos conhecidos como WS-* (e.g., [WS-Addressing](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-core/), [WS-Reliable Messaging](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702), [WS-Security](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=wss), entre outros.
- [WADL (Web Application Description Language)](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/) é usado para descrever "serviços web", também conhecidos como "serviços HTTP" ou ainda "serviços REST" (ainda que não sigam a especificação REST estritamente).

De modo geral, as frameworks para a definição de serviços SOAP são mais poderosas (e mais complicadas) que aquelas que são usadas para serviços HTTP. Se você já tem um serviço e só quer descrevê-lo, você deverá usar a linguagem de descrição (WSDL ou WADL) apropriada. Se o serviço ainda vai ser desenvolvido, dependendo dos requisitos você irá escolher um modelo ou o outro.

YMMV, mas nos últimos anos a tendência vem sendo para a implementação de mais serviços HTTP puro (principalmente por serem mais fácil de serem acessados por dispositivos móveis) que os serviços SOAP, mas como quase tudo na vida, a resposta certa depende da sua situação.